# Integration by parts. Help please $\int r^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{16+r^{2}}} dr$

Tags: integration

I am having trouble identifying what to do. I get stuck after the first IBP.

$\int r^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{16+r^{2}}} dr$

My goal is to use the arctan 1/a tan^-1(x/a) but I cannot get rid of the sqrt.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try $r^2+16=t^2$

Differentiate, $2rdr=2tdt$

$$\int r^2 \frac{tdt}{t}$$

$$\int(t^2-16)dt$$

Can you do it now?

Comment: What rules are you using? And thanks for responding! I havent figured it out though

Comment: @user4681 Simple substitution. I wrote $r^3 $as $r^2.r$.

Comment: @Awesome - that was... Awesome! Nice answer!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $$x = r^2$$ substitution, so $$ dx = 2r dr$$ With that you get the simpler $$ \int x \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{16+x}}dx$$ integral where you can use IBP.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other solutions suggest, integration by parts is not really needed here.  The easiest substitution that works here is 
$$x=r^2+16,dx=2rdr$$
$$\int\dfrac{r^3dr}{\sqrt{16+r^2}}=\frac12\int\dfrac{r^2\times2rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+16}}=\frac12\int\frac{x-16}{\sqrt x}dx=\int\frac12x^{1/2}dx-\int8x^{-1/2}dx$$

at which point it's now trivial.  If you really wanted to do this with integration by parts, I'd recommend choosing $u=\frac12r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $16 + r^2 = t^2$. 
Then $2rdr = 2tdt$.
And write the numerator as $r^2 \cdot r$. 
So $r^2 = t^2 - 16$ , 
your integral will change into  integral of $(t^2 -16)dt $. 
After this it is easy.